# How to parse this content in kibana using grok pattern?

Tags: kibana, logstash-grok

The message in kibana is:

```
{"log":"2024-02-01 10:30:00.004  INFO 1 --- [pool-1-thread-2] c.ankon.timer.ReminderExecCheckSchedule  : Detecting Timed ，start...\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2024-02-01T02:30:00.01291984Z"}
```

I'm trying to write a grok expression to do the matching:

```
%{QS:LOGTYPE}:%{QS:CONTENT},%{QS:ST}:%{QS:TIME}:%{QS:timestamp}
```

But it's not right

The question 1:

I'd like to ask how the grok expression should be written to match the above.

The question 2:

If I want the end result to be:

```
{"log":"2024-02-01 10:30:00.004  INFO 1 --- [pool-1-thread-2] c.ankon.timer.ReminderExecCheckSchedule  : Detecting Timed ，start...\n"}
```

What is the content of the grok pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use built-in Grok Debugger in Kibana.
http://localhost:5601/app/dev_tools#/grokdebugger

Input

```
{"log":"2024-02-01 10:30:00.004  INFO 1 --- [pool-1-thread-2] c.ankon.timer.ReminderExecCheckSchedule  : Detecting Timed ，start...\n","stream":"stdout","time":"2024-02-01T02:30:00.01291984Z"}
```

output:

```
{
  "loglevel": "INFO",
  "thread": "1",
  "message": "Detecting Timed ，start...\\n\",\"stream\":\"stdout\",\"time\":\"2024-02-01T02:30:00.01291984Z\"}",
  "class": "c.ankon.timer.ReminderExecCheckSchedule ",
  "timestamp": "2024-02-01 10:30:00.004",
  "threadname": "pool-1-thread-2"
}
```

You can use the following link to see all grok patterns.
https://github.com/hpcugent/logstash-patterns/blob/master/files/grok-patterns

**The question 2:**
If you want the end result like the following:

```
{"log":"2024-02-01 10:30:00.004  INFO 1 --- [pool-1-thread-2] c.ankon.timer.ReminderExecCheckSchedule  : Detecting Timed ，start...\n"}
```

you can use another grok like this:

```
%{DATA:raw_data}\\n
```

The above grok pattern will parse the data and only take the part **before** `\n`

[image]

Comment: You're welcome Andrew.

Comment: Musab Dogan, Can you help me with another question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77918739/can-the-kibana-interface-be-grouped-for-projects

Comment: Answered, hope it works.