# Can the Kibana interface be grouped for projects?

Tags: kibana-7

I am using ELK 7.4.

There are 3 projects: A , B and C.

Each of the 3 projects captures front-end logs and back-end logs, my question is can I implement grouping in the Kibana interface? Each project is a group, after clicking on the group, you can select the front-end logs and back-end logs to view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**After Kibana version 6.5, you can use [kibana spaces](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/7.14/xpack-spaces.html) for multi tenancy.**

**You can configure the roles for [each user](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/tutorial-secure-access-to-kibana.html#_spaces) for authentication.**

[image]

Comment: Musab Dogan, thanks very much , I'll try.

Comment: Musab Dogan，Please help me how to solve this problem?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78098601/can-kibana-enable-automatic-monthly-auto-creation-of-indexes-for-different-space

Comment: Hey Andrew, let me check!