# Can kibana enable automatic monthly auto-creation of indexes for different spaces?

Tags: logstash, kibana-7

I use space in ELK to put different indexes in different space：

[image]

my indexes are created on a monthly basis, part of my logstash is configured as shown below:

[image]

Currently I create indexes manually, is it possible to create indexes automatically for different spaces every month? If so, how should I do it? If not, is there an interface that I can write a script to do so?

Comment: Hey @andrew, creating a space per month is not best practice. What is the main goal that you want to achive?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a tenant (space) per month is not a best practice but you can follow the below steps if you really want.

**You can create a space per month with spaces API call.**
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/spaces-api.html

```
curl -X POST "localhost:5601/api/spaces/space" -H 'kbn-xsrf: true' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "id": "dashboard-2024-03",
  "name": "dashboard-2024-03",
  "description" : "This is the March 2024 Space",
  "color": "#aabbcc",
  "initials": "MD",
  "disabledFeatures": [],
  "imageUrl": "data:image/png;base64,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"
}
'
```

**You can manage roles and can add specific index/alias to a space with role management API call.**
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/role-management-api.html

```
curl -X PUT "localhost:5601/api/security/role/role-2024-03" -H 'kbn-xsrf: true' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "elasticsearch": {
    "cluster": [ "all" ],
    "indices": [
      {
        "names": [ "index-2024-03" ],
        "privileges": [ "read" ]
      }
    ],
  "kibana": [
    {
      "feature": {
        "discover": [ "read" ],
        "dashboard": [ "read" ]
      },
      "spaces": [ "marketing" ]
    }
  ]
}
'
```

Now a new space called `dashboard-2024-03` and a new role called `role-2024-03` created. In the `dashboard-2024-03` dashboard the only visible data is the data in `index-2024-03` index.

Additional note: To give access only to a specific dashboard you [can create a new user](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-put-user.html) and assign only `role-2024-03` to that user.

Comment: Musab Dogan，What I mean is to add new indexes under space every month when space is already fixed, with the following index names: pms-202402, pms-202403

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I understand and the above example is fit for your expectation